# Proving that an equivalence class is a filter

Tags: logic

Let be A a field of subsets of a non empty set X, then $F=[X]$ with the usual equivalence relation between two sets: A is congruent with B iff $ \exists D \in F$ such that $A ∩ D = B ∩ D$. So I have to prove that F is a filter if the cardinal of $A/$$ \cong$ is more than 1. I could prove the propierty of intersection, but for proving the other two propierties I couldnt. The empty set doenst belong to the filter and if a set contains a set of the filter then is in the filter.

The second question is if the cardinal is 2 then is an ultrafilter.

Thanks for the helping!

Comment: What do you mean by $[X]$?

Comment: the structure of $A, ∅, X, ∪, ∩, $complement  and the set is the equivalence class of X with this congruence relation.

Comment: That’s circular. You can define $F$ if you already have the relation, and you can define the relation if you already have $F$, but you have to have one of them to start with. Which one are you assuming is given, $F$, or the equivalence relation?

Comment: I mean this is the congruence relation in a filter. You have the equivalence relation in the structure and then you can define a set with the equivalence relation in the structure of X

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question. Are you given the filter, from which you define an equivalence relation on $A$ by saying that $A\cong B$ iff $\exists D\in F$ such that $A\cap D=B\cap D$? Or are you given an equivalence relation on $A$, from which you define $F$ to be the equivalence class of $X$?

Comment: I think is the second option, because u have an equivalence relation on the structure and then u can define F to the equivalence class of X